# Java Async wait for finish

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Ho do i get my function to wait for being done with it's async task before returning the variable?

```
public boolean CheckOnline(){
    OnlineAsyncTask onlinetsk = new OnlineAsyncTask();
    onlinetsk.execute();
    return Online;
}
```

Comment: Then it should be not async. Execute it in a normal thread and call `join()` on the thread object, to wait until it finishes. Make sure you don't block the UI-thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `get()` to wait for the async task to complete and retrieve the result.

However that defeats the purpose of an async task - it's no longer asynchronous. Consider redesigning your app so that you don't need to wait for a result. Instead e.g. use a callback interface to notify that the async task has finished and a result is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str_result= new OnlineAsyncTask().execute().get();
```

This will make it wait till it returns the value

Comment: Would this also then run on the main thread and not on a separate thread?